# airflow errors building a dag

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to create a DAG that does this

[image]

but when I try this

```py
with DAG(
    dag_id="dag_example",
    schedule_interval="@once",
        default_args={
        "owner": "airflow",
        "start_date": datetime(2020, 11, 1),
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=10),
    },
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    tA = PythonOperator(
        task_id="A",
        python_callable=A,
        provide_context=True,
    ),
    tB = PythonOperator(
        task_id="B",
        python_callable=B,
        provide_context=True,
    ),
    taS = PythonOperator(
        task_id="aS",
        python_callable=aS,
        provide_context=True,
    ),
    taF = PythonOperator(
        task_id="aF",
        python_callable=aF,
        provide_context=True,
    ),
    tbS = PythonOperator(
        task_id="bS",
        python_callable=A,
        provide_context=True,
    ),
    tbF = PythonOperator(
        task_id="bF",
        python_callable=A,
        provide_context=True,
    )
    tA >> tB 
    tA >> taS 
    tA >> taF 
    tB >> tbF 
    tB >> tbS
```

I get the following Traceback error

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

swapping the bitwise operators out for the following

```py
tA.set_downstream(tB)
tA.set_downstream(taS)
tA.set_downstream(taF)
tB.set_downstream(tbS)
tB.set_downstream(tbF)
```

throws this error

Broken DAG:Traceback (most recent call last):
tA.set_downstream(tB)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_downstream'

trying to build this in the dag like so:

```py
with DAG(
    dag_id="dag_example",
    schedule_interval="@once",
        default_args={
        "owner": "airflow",
        "start_date": datetime(2020, 11, 1),
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=10),
        # "on_failure_callback": snow_fail,
        # "on_success_callback": snow_succ,
    },
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    chain(
        PythonOperator(
            task_id="A",
            python_callable=A,
            provide_context=True,
        ),
        [
            PythonOperator(
                task_id="aF",
                python_callable=aF,
                provide_context=True,
                trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
            ),
            PythonOperator(
                task_id="B",
                python_callable=B,
                provide_context=True,
            ),
            [
                PythonOperator(
                    task_id="bF",
                    python_callable=bF,
                    provide_context=True,
                    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
            ),
                PythonOperator(
                    task_id="bS",
                    python_callable=bS,
                    provide_context=True,
                    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
            ),        
            ],
            PythonOperator(
                task_id="aS",
                python_callable=aS,
                provide_context=True,
                trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
            ),
        ],
    )
```

throws this error:

Broken DAG:  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1377, in set_downstream
self._set_relatives(task_or_task_list, upstream=False, edge_modifier=edge_modifier)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1313, in _set_relatives
task_object.update_relative(self, not upstream)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update_relative'

I can get somewhat closer with this, but it's not exactly what I'm trying to accomplish

```py
with DAG(
    dag_id="dag_example",
    schedule_interval="@once",
        default_args={
        "owner": "airflow",
        "start_date": datetime(2020, 11, 1),
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=10),
        # "on_failure_callback": snow_fail,
        # "on_success_callback": snow_succ,
    },
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    chain(
        PythonOperator(
            task_id="A",
            python_callable=A,
            provide_context=True,
        ),
        [
            PythonOperator(
                task_id="aF",
                python_callable=aF,
                provide_context=True,
                trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
            ),
            PythonOperator(
                task_id="aS",
                python_callable=aS,
                provide_context=True,
                trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
            ),
        ],
        PythonOperator(
            task_id="B",
            python_callable=B,
            provide_context=True,
        ),
        [
            PythonOperator(
                task_id="bF",
                python_callable=bF,
                provide_context=True,
                trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
            ),
            PythonOperator(
                task_id="bS",
                python_callable=bS,
                provide_context=True,
                trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
            ),        
        ],
    )
```

as that results in the following DAG

[image]

I'm not sure what else to try

and I do not understand why the bitwise operators are not working?

I also tried BranchPythonOperator for A and that did not work either

Comment: It's a typo.  You have commas at the end of all of those `PythonOperator` statements.  That comma takes the result and turns it into a one-element tuple.  Just kill the commas and you should be good.